# Page transition not working

Tags: android, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to develop a sample note application. The application includes an index page having two `div` elements using `data-role="page"` option. The first page includes two buttons. Clicking on any button should navigate to other `div` using page transition as slide.

Here is my HTML Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dbsample</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="css/cordova.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom-theme.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="css/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                margin: 0; /* Setting body margins to 0 to have proper positioning of #container div */
            }

            /* #container div with absolute position and 100% width and height so it takes up whole window */
            #container {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).one("mobileinit", function () {

                // Setting #container div as a jqm pageContainer
                $.mobile.pageContainer = $('#container');

                // Setting default page transition to slide
                $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'slide';

            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div data-role="page" id="homePage">
                <div data-role="header">
                    <h1>Notes</h1>
                </div>
            <div data-role="content" id="mainContent">  
                <ul data-role="listview" id="noteTitleList">
                </ul>
            </div>  

            <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" style="bottom: 0; position: absolute !important; top: auto !important; width: 100%;">
                <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#editPage" data-transition="slide" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-icon="plus">
                                Add
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#editPage" data-transition="slide" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-icon="grid">
                                Edit
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="editPage">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Notes</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content" id="mainContent">

                <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="textinput">
                    <label for="textinput1" style="margin-top: 2%;">
                        Title
                    </label>
                    <input name="" id="textinput1" placeholder="" value="" type="text">
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="textarea">
                    <label for="textinput2" style="margin-top: 2%; height: 60px;">
                        Details
                    </label>
                    <input name="" id="textinput2" placeholder="" value="" type="text">
                </div>
                <div style="margin-left: 30%; margin-right: 30%;">
                    <input type="submit" data-theme="a" value="Submit">
                </div>
                <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" 
                     style="bottom: 0; position: absolute !important; top: auto !important; width: 100%;">
                    <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#homePage" data-transition="slide" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-icon="home">
                                    Home
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I tried to run this on avd, it seems like the data transitions were simply ignored.
In logcat it throws an error:

```
"file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 15 : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $"
```

Don't know the reason. Any help?

Comment: Are you sure that you have correctly included jquery? Open up a browser and make sure you don't get an error about that. And make sure you can run jquery commands in the javascript console.

Answer (score 0):

`mobileinit` event is not getting fired. You need to register the event before jquery mobile is loaded so that as soon as JQM is loaded the event gets fired. Load JQM script after the following script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).one("mobileinit", function () {

            // Setting #container div as a jqm pageContainer
            $.mobile.pageContainer = $('#container');

            // Setting default page transition to slide
            $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'slide';

        });
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanx for taking a look...Tried yours solution but not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one. It should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dbsample</title>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
        body {
            /* Setting body margins to 0 to have proper positioning of #container div */
            margin: 0;
        }

            /* #container div with absolute position and 100% width and height so it takes up whole window */
        #container {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

</style>

</head>

<body>
 <div id="container">
<div data-role="page" id="homePage">
    <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Notes</h1>
        </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="mainContent">  
        <ul data-role="listview" id="noteTitleList">
        </ul>
    </div>  

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" style="bottom: 0; position: absolute !important; top: auto !important; width: 100%;">
        <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#editPage" data-transition="slide" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-icon="plus">
                        Add
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#editPage" data-transition="slide" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-icon="grid">
                        Edit
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="editPage">
    <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Notes</h1>
        </div>

    <div data-role="content" id="mainContent">

    <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="textinput">
                <label for="textinput1" style="margin-top: 2%;">
                    Title
                </label>
                <input name="" id="textinput1" placeholder="" value="" type="text">
            </div>
         <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="textarea">
                <label for="textinput2" style="margin-top: 2%; height: 60px;">
                    Details
                </label>
                <input name="" id="textinput2" placeholder="" value="" type="text">
            </div>
            <div style="margin-left: 30%; margin-right: 30%;">
            <input type="submit" data-theme="a" value="Submit">
            </div>
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" style="bottom: 0; position: absolute !important; top: auto !important; width: 100%;">
            <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#homePage" data-transition="slide" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-icon="home">
                            Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tried this bt not working...If its working on your side ..will you plz give me a jsfiddle link for that.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like

```
$(document).one("mobileinit", function () {
```

should be:

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
```

Comment: did the same but still not working.any other suggestion to make it work?